# Setting className in dyamically created table cell in angular is not working

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I dynamically add a new row to a table in angular typescript. Then I use `insertCell()` to add cells to the row.  It works, however the new cells do not take on the css *className* properties, despite setting it.

**.ts**

```
    let row = table.insertRow(-1);
    cell = row.insertCell(-1);
    cell.innerHTML = amount;
    cell.className = 'dv';
```

**.css**

```
.nutrition td.dv {
  font-weight : lighter;
    text-align : right;
}
```

**.html**

```
<table id="nutrition-table" class="nutrition">
```

The new dynamically created row/cells are added to the table.  I think the problem has something to do with the way angular accesses dom elements, but I can't figure out how.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried cell.classList.add("dv") instead of assigning className?

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work either.

Comment: Perhaps a link to a CodeSandbox or other similar tool demonstrating the problem would be valuable at this point.